# Use same button event for both Jquery/Primefaces

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I have a command button in primefaces that update a hidden input as shown below :

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<title>Wizard Invoice </title>
</h:head>

<h:outputScript library="Scripts" name="stepsWizard.js" />

<h:body>
<h:form>

<p:commandButton id="IdA" value="test" action="#{invoiceWizardBean.someMethod}" update="hid"/>
<h:inputHidden id="hid" type="hidden" name="name1" value="#{invoiceWizardBean.somevalue}" ></h:inputHidden>

<input id="IdB" type="button" value="submit" />  


</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

After clicking in the button IdA the value of my hidden input is updated correctly in DOM.(Without using any Jquery in client side), but If add a method that do extra operations using the same button the value is no more correct

```
jQuery(function($) {
var buttonNext = $("#j_idt6\\:IdA");
buttonNext.click(function(){
    var valueHidden = $("#j_idt6\\:hid")[0].value;
    console.log(valueHidden);
    // valueHidden has the previous value. It is not updated !!
    // Do some operations based in valueHidden value
});
});
```

If I change my jquery function and use the Button IdB, valueHidden is correct.

It's important that I use the same button to make the operations in my client side.

Any Ideas please ?

Comment: Please create a full but minimal example (see [ask]) and be more specific about the value not being correct (is it always 666?). And what is it that you functionally want

Comment: Hello Kukeltje, I've updated the post with the maximum of details. Thanks.

Comment: I see you made some changes, but I still fail to see what you functionally (not technically) want to achieve. It might be that you are falling into the [XY trap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you should use the `oncomplete` of the `<p:commandButton` ,

something like this

```
<p:commandButton oncomplete="myJsFunc()" id="IdA" value="test" 
    action="#{invoiceWizardBean.someMethod}" update="hid"/>
```

Place your client side logic into that javascript function called myJsFunc